# Extract the second quoted string in a line of output

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, cut

I have a line of output with three quotes, and I specifically need to extract the *second* quote into a variable. So for example, with the command `cmd | grep tokens`, I get the following output:

Output

```
"abcde", "12345", "zyxwv"
```

I need to pull `12345` out of there. The closest I've gotten is by adding `| cut '\"' -f2` to the command, but that returns "abcde". How can I get the second quote rather than the first?

Comment: where is this string coming from?  it it possible that there will be quote-marks embedded in the strings?

Comment: Is it possible that the might be unquoted strings in the input?

Answer (score 2):

Just improve your `cut` command. You're specifying the delimiter as `"` so count the fields before each `"`.

For example

Before the first `"` ther's nothing so:

```
$ echo "\"abcde\", \"12345\", \"zyxwv\"" | cut -d \" -f 1
[empty]
```

Before the second `"` is `abcde`

```
$ echo "\"abcde\", \"12345\", \"zyxwv\"" | cut -d \" -f2
abcde
```

Before the third `"` is `,`

```
$ echo "\"abcde\", \"12345\", \"zyxwv\"" | cut -d \" -f3
,
```

So your expected output will be the fourth one

```
$ echo "\"abcde\", \"12345\", \"zyxwv\"" | cut -d \" -f4
12345
```

I hope the escape backslash don't mess you

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
variable=$(cmd | grep tokens | cut -d',' -f 2 | sed 's/ //')
```

Comment: Not exactly but it does the trick. Thank you!!

Comment: This will print also the quotes, then you must make other `sed` substitution for those

Comment: No it does not! I tried this `echo Output tokens: "abcde", "12345", "zyxwv" | cut -d',' -f 2 | sed 's/ //` and got 12345

Answer (score 0):

We can simply do it with awk

eg:

> [user@test ~]$ echo "abcde", "12345", "zyxwv" | awk -F"," '{print $2}'
>    12345

if the output is coming from a cmd then

> > var='`<cmd> | awk -F"," '{print $2}'`

Comment: There are unbalanced quotes in the second command. And in the first command, `awk` actually receives unquoted input due to the way you pass it with `echo`.

Comment: In the second command i actually want to add the quote which is in the tilde key but while posting it is not printing the actual quote.

Comment: It's better to use `$( ... )` than backticks in any case.